# AjaxControlToolkit Asyncfileupload with master page not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax AsyncFileUpload control in asp.net 4.0 with master page and I get error that file is invalid. If I use it without master page, it works. With master page If I set

```
ClientIDMode="AutoID"
```

It start working. What is purpose of ClientIDMode and why AsyncFileupload is not working without ClientMode with master page.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_). This algorithm was used in versions of ASP.NET earlier than ASP.NET 4.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The client side script got confused because it couldn’t find the predicted `ClientID`.